# PHP code that is deprecated

Tags: php

Ok I am not a PHP boffin so I have taken an old website and restoring it slowly but surely.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="****"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="****"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="****"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE id>0 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,15");
?>
```

Connect to the server part is what concerns me I understand that it is deprecated and that i should use MySQLi ad or PDO

Question is do I just change the mysql_query to mysqli to alter this or do I need to change a lot of the other coding. I have read the http://php.net/mysql_query but still not sure how to rectify this

Comment: Read the documentation! http://php.net/mysqli **Everything** you need to know is there.

Comment: "Not being a PHP boffin" does not mean "not reading the doc" - http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.query.php even gives you an example.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) if you want to use PDO. For MySQLi everything has been said.

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about) have some good information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a simple one-for-one replacement, there are some differences. You can download a conversion tool from [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi) that will help with most of the code.

ALso, one of the benefits of mysqli and PDO is *prepared statements*, which should be used instead of interpolating strings into your queries. The conversion tool will not do this work for you.

Comment: Great thanks guys some more reading I will do and thank you for the converter as well.

Comment: @TrevorAckermann FYI the Oracle converter tool sucks. It uses a global variable to emulate the way ext/mysql doesn't require you to pass the connection resource because often the injection chain is not in place in the code. One major point of using MySQLi or PDO is prepared statements, which requires learning why to use them, how they work, and rewriting the code to implement them. Just converting your existing code call-for-call is *almost* pointless, all you gain is that PHP 5.5 won't throw `E_DEPRECATED` warnings. Also my personal opinion is that MySQLi sucks and you should use PDO anyway.

Comment: For those who cannot find the tool, because all the links are dead, use [google to search for it](https://www.google.ro/search?q=mysqli_converter-1.0.zip). Just make sure the code you downloaded is safe.